# How to get this simple Python 2 code to work in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x

I am learning variable nested loops and this is the code in Python 2.

```
numLines = int(raw_input ('How many lines of stars do you want? '))
numStars = int(raw_input ('How many stars per line? '))
for line in range(0, numLines):
    for star in range(0, numStars): 
        print '*',
    print
```

This is the desired output (in Python 2):

```
How many lines of stars do you want? 3
How many stars per line? 3
* * *
* * *
* * *
```

But I am having a hard time getting Python 3 to achieve the same effect.

Here is my best attempt with getting the same output using Python 3:

```
numLines = int(input('How many lines of stars do you want? '))
numStars = int(input('How many stars per line? '))
for line in range(0, numLines):
    for star in range(0, numStars): 
        print('*', end=" ")
    print
```

Please advise.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Add `()` to the end of that.

Comment: Without a traceback, we have no way to help you.

Comment: In Python 3.x , `print` is a function (not a statement) , you need to call it for it to print . Example - `print()` (Referring to the last line in your code).

Answer (score 3):

In python 3, print should be used as a function, not a statement. So, the last line in your outer loop body needs to be `print()`, not `print`.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone who commented constructively. Here is the code that finally works for me:

```
numLines = int(input('How many lines of stars do you want? '))
numStars = int(input('How many stars per line? '))
for line in range(0, numLines):
    for star in range(0, numStars): 
        print('*', end=" ")
    print()
```

By the way, what is a traceback? (serious question)

And how would it help you to answer this simple question of mine ? (serious question)

Comment: A traceback is what happens when Python stops your code and displays an error. It is called a trace back because it traces back through the steps the computer had taken to execute your code a few steps to help you locate the problem. [Relevant Wikipedia Article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_trace), and here's a [question on SO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_trace) about them (in Java, but same idea).

Comment: In reference to the earlier comment, we often ask for a traceback because it is far more descriptive and helpful -- provided you know how to read it -- than vague user descriptions ("it doesn't work") or paraphrases of it ("I get a UnicodeDecodeError" when the traceback would also say what line, what call, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

In Python, `print()` is a function, and should be treated as such. `print` doesn't work, because you need parameters. For an empty string, you don't put in parameters, but you do need the `()` after `print` so it runs the print function.